# A is a linearly dependent set iff there are some vectors in A can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

X is a vector space on a field F and
$$ A \subset X $$
and
$$ A=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\} $$
A is a linearly dependent set iff there are some vectors in A can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.

$$ \Rightarrow : $$
A is linearly dependent then
$$ \exists c_1,c_2,...,c_n$$ such that
$$ c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n=0  $$
and $$ \exists c_i =0 ,(1\le i \le n) $$
then $$ c_i = \frac{-c_1}{c_i} v_1- \frac{c_2}{c_i}v_2+...- \frac{c_{i-1}}{c_i}v_{i-1}- \frac{c_{i+1}}{c_i} v_{i+1} +...- \frac{c_n}{c_i}v_n $$
if we say $$ a_k= \frac{-c_k}{c_i} \in F $$ then proof done.
$$ \Leftarrow : $$
I can prove that there are some vectors in A can be expressed as a linear combination of the preceding elements.
that means :
$$ v_k \in A : v_k\in Span\{v_1,v_2,...,v_{k-1}\} $$.but I don't know how can I prove that this vector in A can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there exists a vector $v_i \in X$ such that there are $x_1,...,x_n \in F$ such that

> $v_i= x_1v_1+...+x_{i-1}v_{i-1}+x_{i+1}v_{i+1}+...+x_nv_n$

then

> $\boldsymbol{0}= x_1v_1+...+x_{i-1}v_{i-1}+(-1)v_i+x_{i+1}v_{i+1}+...+x_nv_n$

And as $-1 \neq 0$ the set $X$ is linearly dependent